# Доступ к свойствам делегата приложения

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Добрый день,

Есть некоторое приложение для ios. В классе XXXAppDelegate есть какое-то свойство X. Как получить доступ к этому полю из объектов других классов?

Очевидно, вопрос очень простой. Но я пока учусь писать под ios и пока не смог найти ответ на этот вопрос.

Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 4):

```
YourAppDelegateName *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegateName *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate someMethodOrProperty];
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло